# AngularJS: Is there any way to determine which fields are making a form invalid?

Tags: validation, angularjs

I have the following code in an AngularJS application, inside of a controller,
which is called from an ng-submit function, which belongs to a form with name `profileForm`:

```
$scope.updateProfile = function() {
  if($scope.profileForm.$invalid) { 
    //error handling..
  }
  //etc.
};
```

Inside of this function, is there any way to figure out which fields are causing the entire form to be called invalid?

Answer (score 96):

Each input `name`'s validation information is exposed as property in `form`'s name in `scope`.

HTML

```
<form name="someForm" action="/">
    <input name="username" required />
    <input name="password" type="password" required />
</form>
```

JS

```
$scope.someForm.username.$valid
// > false
$scope.someForm.password.$error
// > { required: true }
```

The exposed properties are `$pristine`, `$dirty`, `$valid`, `$invalid`, `$error`.

If you want to iterate over the errors for some reason:

```
$scope.someForm.$error
// > { required: [{$name: "username", $error: true /*...*/},
//                {$name: "password", /*..*/}] }
```

Each rule in error will be exposed in $error.

Here is a plunkr to play with http://plnkr.co/edit/zCircDauLfeMcMUSnYaO?p=preview

Comment: Warning to others falling into my trap - you must specify the `name` attribute of the input to see it in $name (of course). The fact that AngularJS binds to a model property without the need for a name can result in it being hard to diagnose which input is invalid.

Comment: The hint of using the $scope object to determine which fields are making a form invalid helped me.

Answer (score 28):

For checking which field of form is invalid

```
console.log($scope.FORM_NAME.$error.required);
```

this will output the array of invalid fields of the form

Answer (score 15):

If you want to see which fields are messing up with your validation and you have jQuery to help you, just search for the *"ng-invalid"* class on the javascript console.

```
$('.ng-invalid');
```

It will list all DOM elements which failed validation for any reason.

Answer (score 12):

You can loop through `form.$error.pattern`.

```
$scope.updateProfile = function() {
    var error = $scope.profileForm.$error;
    angular.forEach(error.pattern, function(field){
        if(field.$invalid){
            var fieldName = field.$name;
            ....
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, except instead of form.$error.pattern, I used form.$error.required.  There is no "pattern" property.  Did that change or something?

Comment: @Anthony that depends the validation type =) see http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html#html5-validators-and-parse-errors

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to display all the errors in the disabled Save button tooltip, so the user will know why is disable instead of scrolling up and down the long form.

#### Note: remember to add name property to the fields in your form

```
    if (frm) {
        disable = frm.$invalid;
        if (frm.$invalid && frm.$error && frm.$error.required) {
            frm.$error.required.forEach(function (error) {
                disableArray.push(error.$name + ' is required'); 
            });
        }
    }
    if (disableArray.length > 0) {
        vm.disableMessage = disableArray.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For my application i display error like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="errs in myForm.$error">
<li ng-repeat="err in errs">{{err.$name}}</li></ul>
```

if you want to see everything, just user 'err' that will display something like this:

```
 "$validators": {},
"$asyncValidators": {},
"$parsers": [],
"$formatters": [],
"$viewChangeListeners": [],
"$untouched": true,
"$touched": false,
"$pristine": true,
"$dirty": false,
"$valid": false,
"$invalid": true,
"$error": { "required": true },
"$name": "errorfieldName",
"$options": {}
```

Not this well formatted, but you will see these things there...

Answer (score 2):

When any field is invalid, if you try to get its value, it will be `undefined`.

Lets say you have a text input attached to `$scope.mynum` that is valid only when you type numbers, and you have typed `ABC` on it.

If you try to get the value of `$scope.mynum`, it would be `undefined`; it wouldn't return the `ABC`.

(Probably you know all this, but anyway)

So, I would use an array that have all the elements that need validation that I have added to the scope and use a filter (with underscore.js for example) to check which ones return as `typeof` `undefined`.

And those would be the fields causing the invalid state.

Comment: Depending on the validation used (e.g. custom validators) model might not always be undefined when invalid.

Comment: @Stewie Hmm yes, that's very true. I guess it does not work on every single case. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find field(s) which invalidates form on UI without programmatically, just right click inspect (open developer tools in elements view) then search for ng-invalid with ctrl+f inside this tab. Then for each field you find ng-invalid class for, you can check if field is not given any value while it is required, or other rules it may violate (invalid email format, out of range / max / min definition,  etc.). This is the easiest way.